# How to sort the renderings by alphabetical order in the "select a Rendering" dialog box which appears on the Experience Editor mode?

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

How can we change the order(to Alphabetical order) of Renderings in the "Select a Rendering" dialog box?

We have tried extending the SelectRenderingForm class which returns no renderings in the dialog box. "None available" message is showing on the "Select a Rendering" dialog box.

[image]

Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Rendering Item -> Sorting -> Subitems Sorting

[image]

Then in the dialog box that opens up, there are various options among which Default or Display Name should help you to sort in alphabetical order

[image]

Comment: This is not working. we need to sort the renderings by alphabetical order in the "Select a Rendering" dialog box which appears on the experience editor mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is working if we are extending the SelectRenderingForm class. The problem that I am facing now is, **SelectRenderingOptions** model is not returning the list of rendering items to be appeared in the "Select a Rendering" dialog when we override the OnLoad method on the extension/derived class.

But, If we put below line in the very beginning of the OnLoad method then it is working as expected.
`SelectRenderingOptions selectRenderingOptions = SelectItemOptions.Parse<SelectRenderingOptions>();`

Instead of keeping next to the following line:
`IsOpenPropertiesChecked = Registry.GetBool("/Current_User/SelectRendering/IsOpenPropertiesChecked");`

If anyone know other solution, please let me know!

[image]

Expected result:
[image]